# Sample of first-year choice statement to be treated as dual-status alien

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident

I am going to make a first-year choice to be treated as dual-status alien for year 2013. Publication 519 says that to make the choice:

> You must attach a statement to Form 1040 to make the first-year choice for 2013. The statement must contain your name and address and specify the following.
>
> - That you are making the first-year choice for 2013.
> - That you were not a resident in 2012.
> - That you are a resident under the substantial presence test in 2014.
> - The number of days of presence in the United States during 2014.
> - The date or dates of your 31-day period of presence and the period of continuous presence in the United States during 2013.
> - The date or dates of absence from the United States during 2013 that you are treating as days of presence.

I am also making the choice for my dependent daughter. I drafted text of the statement below. Could you help me find any mistakes and suggest what needs to be corrected?

> Internal Revenue Service
>
> From: Antonio Bernulli
>   Address:
>       1111 Chemical Elements St, Apt 111
>       Omg City, WY 11111
>
> Dear Sir or Madam:
>
> This is written to declare that I elect to be treated as a resident for part of year 2013 (first-year choice).
>
> I was not a resident in 2012. I am a resident under substantial presense test in 2014.
>
> Number of days of presense in the United States during 2014 (as of June 20, 2014): 153
>   Date of 31-day period of presence in the United States during 2013: 10/1/2013
>   Period of continuous presence in the United States during 2013: 10/1/2013 - 12/31/2013
>
> **Election on behalf of dependent child**
>
> I make an election on behalf of my daughter to treat her as a resident for part of year 2013 (first-year choice).
>
> She was not a resident in 2012. She is a resident under substantial presense test in 2014.
>
> Number of days of presense in the United States during 2014 (as of June 20, 2014): 153
>   Date of 31-day period of presence in the United States during 2013: 10/1/2013
>   Period of continuous presence in the United States during 2013: 10/1/2013 - 12/31/2013
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Antonio Bernulli.

Comment: Why do you need to make an election for your daughter? Are you filing a separate tax return on her behalf?

Comment: @littleadv, I am not filing a separate tax return on her behalf. If I don't make an election for her, she will be non-resident alien, and I won't be able to treat her as dependent.